# Convert HH:MM:SS AM/PM OBJECT column to SECONDS

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time

I have an Object Type column with time in format of HH:MM:SS AM/PM. output I need is a column with this time object column converted to Seconds.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
df={'time_col':['10:10:10 PM','02:00:05 AM'],'time_seconds':[72610,7205]}
df2=pd.DataFrame(df)
```

I tried different ways. However, it is adding 1900-01-01 to some rows and not to some rows.

Comment: Seconds with the respect to what? The start of the day or some date? If the latter, you need to add the date to your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert time string to `datetime` (to account for AM/PM), take the string of the time component (ignore date), and convert that to `timedelta`. Now you can extract the seconds.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time_col':['10:10:10 PM','02:00:05 AM']})

# make sure we have time objects
df['time_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_col']).dt.time

# time column to string, then to timedelta and extract seconds from that
df['time_seconds'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time_col'].astype(str)).dt.total_seconds()

df['time_seconds']
0    79810.0
1     7205.0
Name: time_seconds, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Got an error,   "<class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime"

Comment: @SrikanthAyithy that means you already have datetime.time objects in the column, you should be able use `pd.to_timedelta(df['time_col'].astype(str)).dt.total_seconds()` then.

Comment: Another error, "only leading negative signs are allowed".

Comment: @SrikanthAyithy ok can you please add a [mre] to your question so the errors are reproducible?

Comment: Thank You. It worked. I separated out the column and created a new column and then applied the latest one. pd.to_timedelta(df['time_col'].astype(str)).dt.total_seconds(). It worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you can fire a pyspark session. This could also work and supplement @MrFuppes answer:

```
df1=spark.createDataFrame(df2)


timeFmt = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
df1.select("time_col", F.unix_timestamp(to_timestamp('time_col', 'hh:mm:ss a'),timeFmt).cast("long").alias("time")).show()

+-----------+-----+
|   time_col| time|
+-----------+-----+
|10:10:10 PM|79810|
|02:00:05 AM| 7205|
+-----------+-----+
```